# Add image in many2one field

Tags: odoo, odoo-13

can someone help me with this, How to add an image in many2one field in odoo 13

I want to add an image in the many2one field means when my dropdown list appears it include the name and the image with it

Answer (score 1):

You can’t add an image directly to a `fields.Many2one` field. Because an image is also a field (`fields.Binary`).

You can create a relational model and next extend your model.
For example, this code enables you to add many photos to your obiect.

In your model add:

```
your_images_ids = fields.One2many(“your.image.model”, “product_id”)
```

in your.image.model (new one) model:

```
… other fields..
yourmodel_id = fields.Many2one(“your.model”)
image = fields.Binary()
```

Then you can extend your view also and try to put photo next to your obiect.